# How are datums retrieved from UTXOs by on-chain code?

Tags: plutus, utxo

How is Plutus on-chain code able to retrieve and decode datums from UTXOs of `ScriptContext`?

These datums are hardly found in cardano-db-sync or explorers anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, only datum *hashes* are able to be a part of the UTXO, so you are only able to *verify* a datum value on chain. Retrieving the datum itself is therefore on off-chain process.

However [CIP-32](https://github.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs/pull/160) is coming very soon (likely end of February/March) and will enable attaching the datum itself to a UTXO, rather than only the datum hash.